# Using the touch bar control strip to play/pause VLC?

Tags: touch-bar, vlc

The play/pause button on the touch bar control strip doesn't seem to have any affect on VLC. Each time it is clicked iTunes ends up getting launched. I'm assuming that there must be a way to control how the widget works? But I'm not sure. A lot of information seems to talk about running applescript for the touch bar widgets. I'm not sure if that is optimal or not.

Ideas?